# Removing slashs in wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I'm struggling to remove a slash of a menu in Wordpress.

I'm editing [this page](http://www.videoramatv.com/). The theme used is awaken. And I'm not sure if that "/" which is between each of the elements of the menu comes for something on the theme being used, or if it's something that wordpress does by default.

I was checking the html generated and I couldnt see the character physically in the code.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some inspection I found that it's a pseudo element `(.top-navigation ul > li > a:before)` within the theme stylesheet, `style.css` line `2364` simply removing the styles should solve your struggle, happy theming!

[image: <code>::before is behind this</code>]

Comment: You, Sir, deserve more points that the ones I can give you. That worked just perfect! Thx!